# How to fit parser in my python script

Tags: python, argparse, optionparser

Normally, if I have to perform an overlap between multiple files, I just execute:

```
python -c 'import sys;print "".join(sorted(set.intersection(*[set(open(a).readlines()) for a in sys.argv[1:]])))' File1 File2 File3 File4 ....
```

But if I have to get this through a parser, how can I do it?

A short example will be enough around this script, and after that I can play around. Actually I want the user to give two input: Files on which ioperation is to be performed and the the operation here it is intersection.

Kindly help, instead of voting the post to close.

I think I have to show what I am doing, and here is an example of that:

```
usage = "Usage: %prog -i <file1>[,<file2>,...] -o <out> -ops "
version = "%prog " + str(VERSION)
parser = OptionParser(version=version, usage=usage)
group1 = OptionGroup(parser, 'Optional')

parser.add_option("-i", 
                  dest="featurefile", 
                  help="Gene list", 
                  metavar="FILE")
parser.add_option("-o", 
                  dest="outfile", 
                  help="output file (type determined by extension)", 
                  metavar="FILE")
# Optional arguments
group1.add_option("--op", 
                  dest="operation", 
                  help="Intersection, Union & Uniques (default Intersection)", 
                  default=None,
                  type="string")

parser.add_option_group(group1)
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Now this set is parser thing (done), now the second step is to get the operation (intersection) and the files and perform them. At this step I am lost.

Thank you

Comment: Note that questions are closed for specific reasons. The best strategy would be to read up on those reasons, and avoid them. People are currently saying that it's _"Unclear what you're asking"_

Comment: Edited few things in question.

Comment: Why not just call `set.intersection` from within the script?

Comment: Can you explain it with a small example, using the above construct. I am learning the language and it would be nice to see the thing thorugh an example.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: 2.7.5 version of python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Python 2.7, use the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) module instead of the older `optparse`:

```
import argparse
import itertools as IT

VERSION = 0.1

version = "%(prog)s " + str(VERSION)
operation = {
    'intersection': set.intersection,
    'union': set.union,
    'uniques': set.difference}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version=version)
parser.add_argument('-i', '--featurefiles', nargs='+', help='Gene list',
                    metavar='FILE')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--outfile', help="output file (type determined by extension)",
                    metavar='FILE')
parser.add_argument('--op', dest="operation", 
                    help="Intersection, Union & Uniques (default Intersection)",
                    default='intersection',
                    # can't use type=operation.get. See http://bugs.python.org/issue16516
                    type=lambda x: operation[x])  

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if args.outfile:
    with open(args.outfile, 'w') as f:
        for group_size in (len(args.featurefiles), 2):
            for group in IT.combinations(args.featurefiles, group_size): 
                result = ''.join(sorted(reduce(
                    args.operation,
                    (set(open(filename))
                     for filename in group))))
                f.write('{g}:\n{r}\n'.format(g=str(group), r=result))
```

You could call the script from the CLI like this:

```
script.py -i file1 file2 file3 --op uniques -o /tmp/out
```

References to tools used above:

- [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)
- [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)
- [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)
- [with-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)
- [str format method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: Thank unubtu, its a very cool and simple solution :) . One last tail question, how can I also get the overlap between individual files. Also, the output is not being written to the output file it is just displayed on screen. Thank you have taught me something very useful method in a very simple way.

Comment: No problem. Question: what do you mean by overlap? isn't the intersection the overlap?

Comment: Yes intersection are overlaps and I meant,if it is possible to get intersection of pairs also along with the final intersection. Now I see the elements that are present in all my files but it would be great if I could also see the elements that are present in A&C, A&B, B&C and so on depending upon number of files. I restrict the number of inputs to 5 files, of course this would automatically create more than one file as an output. Thank you.

Comment: I've added some code showing how you could compute the pairwise set operations.

Comment: Thanks again, the newer version shows only pairwise and misses the complete overlap.

Comment: The complete overlap is listed at the end. You could make it the first by changing `(2, len(args.featurefiles))` to `(len(args.featurefiles), 2)`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was using head instead of cat to visualise results.

Comment: Great worked with 2 functions i.e., intersection and union but not with uniques :(

Comment: I am taking `uniques` to mean `set.symmetric_difference`. If that's not what you intend, then there is the problem. Sorry I have to go now, but hopefully this will give you a start in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks :)  yes, I will try to figure out and indeed I meant the difference.